# While loop failing to parse data on zsh, worked in bash on MacOS

Tags: macos, zsh

I'm having an issue that previously worked with bash in macOS that I've used for years and now it seems to be failing on macOS Ventura with zsh. Below is a script that loops through a .csv file line by line.

The initial loop

```
cat /Users/$currentUser/Documents/$input | while IFS= read -r pilotuser
```

always returns a result as I've validated here

```
echo "pilotuser: $pilotuser"
```

However in the past in bash I would get the result

```
echo "uuidlist: $uuidlist" >> /Users/$currentUser/Documents/$output
```

which would return something like this

```
1234-1234-3456-6789-0123
```

I've run these 2 commands locally on the device and get the desired result that I expect but when I run the script it never returns the result from the second command. I'm lost and and can't seem to figure out where this is failing so I'm reaching out for anyone that could help.

```
#!/bin/zsh

#*************************************************************************#
function loop2 (){ 
    currentUser=$(ls -l /dev/console | awk '{print $3}')
    input="input.csv"
    output="output"
    
    cat /Users/$currentUser/Documents/$input | while IFS= read -r pilotuser ; do
        echo "pilotuser: $pilotuser"
        uuidlist=$(cat /Users/$currentUser/Documents/file.json | grep -B2 $pilotuser)
        echo "uuidlist: $uuidlist" >> /Users/$currentUser/Documents/$output
    done
}
#*************************************************************************#

loop2
```

Comment: Is there a reason `$USER` isn't an accurate enough way to get the current user? (It's [POSIX-specified](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html)!)

Comment: and btw, `cat` is relatively inefficient; better to `grep foo <file` than to `cat file | grep foo`. (It's a bigger difference with other tools -- `tail` for example runs in constant time given a direct seekable FD, but O(n) time given a FIFO -- meaning that being in the habit of providing real file handles whenever possible can sometimes have very substantial returns).

Comment: Bigger picture, though, run your code with xtrace enabled (`zsh -x yourscript`) and see where it gets stuck; that'll enable you to ask a more focused question.

Comment: (And as a performance thing, consider putting something like `4>>outputfile` _after the `done`_ and then using `>&4` on every line you want to go to that file; that way you open the file only once and leave it open throughout the loop, instead of re-opening it every single time you want to write a line there).

Comment: You don't even need `$currentUser`. `$HOME` is the current user's home directory. You can also use `~/Documents/$input`

Comment: Don't use `grep` to extract from a JSON file. Install `jq` and use that.

Comment: Can you provide small samples of `input.csv` and `file.json` that we can try? I have Ventura.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy so I'm pulling from a different area and simplified the script so that's why I didn't use $USER for the home directory.

Comment: @Barmar I will have to scrub some of the data in order to post a sample. I also run this script on other users Macs that I manage so I try and use what is installed by default to not add complexity.

Comment: You really ought to take more care about quoting variable expansions.  That's probably not what's causing your script to fail, but some day it *will* come back to bite you.

Comment: Have you asked [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) for its opinion of your script?

Comment: @JohnBollinger
Didn't think of using ShellCheck but apparently it doesn't like zsh

```#!/bin/zsh
^-- SC1071 (error): ShellCheck only supports sh/bash/dash/ksh scripts. Sorry!

Comment: Since it started as a Bash script, it makes sense to see what ShellCheck says about it if you test it that way.  And since this seems to be a portability issue, it might make sense to test it as `sh` to see where you're depending on extensions that might vary between Bash and Zsh.

Comment: So I tried to narrow this down more and I replaced the variable $uuidlist with a string test.test that I know exists in the file. When I did this I get a result for the variable $uuidlist, which tells me that even though $pilotuser does give me an output, it's not passing the variable $pilotuser into the command below which that variable is always blank. I just don't know why

```uuidlist=$(cat /Users/$currentUser/Documents/file.json | grep -B2 $pilotuser)```